# GraphQL VSCode Plugin Configuration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, graphql

I am having an issue configuring GraphQL with VS Code.
I am using .graphqlrc which is located in the root directory of TS Project. I am not able to find a clear guidance on how to get this simple thing going.

.graphqlrc

```
projects:
  foo:
       schema: 'graphql/schema.gql'
       documents: 'graphql/*.gql'
```

Error:

```
schema.gql' doesn't match any project
```

Comment: Check the yaml indents.  Schema and documents should be nested under foo.

Comment: that was a copy-paste issue, the indentation is correct in the project.